# golang protobuf remove omitempty tag from generated json tags

Tags: go, grpc, protocol-buffers, proto3

I am using google grpc with a json proxy. for some reason i need to remove the `omitempty` tags from the struct generated in the *.pb.go files.

if i have a proto message like this

```
message Status {
  int32 code = 1;
  string message = 2;
}
```

The generated struct looks like this

```
type Status struct {
  Code int32 `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=code" json:"code,omitempty"`
  Message string `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=message" json:"message,omitempty"`
}
```

But My need is to remove the `omitempty` tag from the generated structs. How can i do this?

Comment: do you need the proto-buf working well? proto-buf need the tags.

Comment: the thing is @JiangYD , i am sending an 0 value with one of my int feild. but when i am sending an 0 value the grpc-gateway omits the value. i know there are other approach, but i would like to know how i can remove an omit empty tag.

Comment: @Sadlil I'm not sure I understand your problem. If you send a `0` value, it will be omitted and thus the field will be left unchanged - properly leaving with value `0` if you used a zero-value struct (which you should anyway).

Comment: my problem is when i parsed the struct into json with a value 0 for Code. the value gets omitted from the json. but i need this value to be present.

Comment: @Sadlil if you explicitly state: `struct.Field = proto.Uint64(0)` it should not be empty.

Answer (score 25):

If you are using grpc-gateway and you need the default values to be present during json marshaling, you may consider to add the following option when creating your servemux

```
    gwmux := runtime.NewServeMux(runtime.WithMarshalerOption(runtime.MIMEWildcard, &runtime.JSONPb{OrigName: true, EmitDefaults: true}))
```

Outside of grpc-gateway, if you want to marshal your protocol buffer message, use `google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson` (*) package instead of `encoding/json`

```
func sendProtoMessage(resp proto.Message, w http.ResponseWriter) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    m := protojson.Marshaler{EmitDefaults: true}
    m.Marshal(w, resp) // You should check for errors here
}
```

(*) `google.golang.org/protobuf` replaces the now [deprecated](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/go.mod) `github.com/golang/protobuf` and its [jsonpb](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/protobuf@v1.5.2/jsonpb) package.

Answer (score 16):

A [more] portable solution:

Use `sed` to strip the tags after generating via `protoc`.

Example of what I actually use in my go:generate script after having generated the *.pb.go files:

```
ls *.pb.go | xargs -n1 -IX bash -c 'sed s/,omitempty// X > X.tmp && mv X{.tmp,}'
```

---

Note: `sed -i` (inline-replacement) is not used here because that flag isn't portable between standard OS-X and Linux.

Answer (score 10):

I found that the `omitempty` json tag is hard-coded into the protoc-gen-go [source](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/84668698ea25b64748563aa20726db66a6b8d299/protoc-gen-go/generator/generator.go#L2243) around line 1778:

```
tag := fmt.Sprintf("protobuf:%s json:%q",
    g.goTag(message, field, wiretype), jsonName+",omitempty")
```

it will be easy changing the source and make a new protoc-gen-go binary yourself.

It's worth noting that this is likely inadvisable and not recommended for several reasons, particularly because you will then be responsible for ensuring that the hacked up binary *always* gets used if the protobufs need to be regenerated.

Answer (score 9):

You can try using gogo proto (https://github.com/gogo/protobuf) 
With the jsontag extension, your proto message would look like

```
message Status {
  int32 code = 1 [(gogoproto.jsontag) = "code"];
  string message = 2 [(gogoproto.jsontag) = "message"];
}
```

You can also add more tags, if you like.

Comment: Nice! In addition, `gogo` supports custom tags e.g. `[ (gogoproto.moretags) = "datastore:\"-\"" ]`. To switch to `gogo`, simply change `protoc --go_out=` to `protoc --gogofast_out=` (note: gogofast is also 5..10 times faster than google proto!)

Answer (score 5):

I am posting an update to DeeSilence's answer that works with the latest protobuf version (at the moment of writing).

```
import "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"

m := protojson.MarshalOptions{EmitUnpopulated: true}
resp, err := m.Marshal(w)
```

Answer (score 3):

The Marshaler under the jsonpb package has a EmitDefaults field. Setting this to true, will just ignore the omitempty tag in struct.

https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb#JSONPBMarshaler

Answer (score 2):

You could use "sed" command to remove this text from files like following

```
sed -i "" -e "s/,omitempty//g" ./api/proto/*.go
```

where args:

1. `-i ""` is meaning that keep same name of files
2. `-e "s/,omitempty//g"` = format to replace like `"s/SEARCH/INSERT/g"`

Comment: This answer from 3+ years ago already suggests using `sed` as a post-process: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37335452/1218512

Answer (score 0):

you can copy the encoding/json package to your own folder for example my_json, and modify [omitEmpty](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.9/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L1156) field to false, and use `my_json.Marshal()` to encode the struct to json string.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @colm.anseo's edit saying that the `google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson` is now deprecated and now [`google.golang.org/protobuf`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.28.1/encoding/protojson#pkg-types) should be used, here is an example how to do it without modifying the proto.

```golang
import (
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
)

func main() {
    someProto := SomeProto{}
    marshaler := protojson.MarshalOptions{EmitUnpopulated: true}
    output, _ := marshaler.Marshal(someProto)
    ... 
}
```

This is the only way to do it if you don't want to modify the generated struct / are importing the struct via buf and the bsr.