# grpc-gateway removed omitempty tag from generated json tags, but empty fields are still not returned

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go, proto3

I am using grpc-gateway v1.16 and I have removed the `omitempty` tags from the struct generated in the *.pb.go files as suggested here -> [golang protobuf remove omitempty tag from generated json tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716238/golang-protobuf-remove-omitempty-tag-from-generated-json-tags)

However, I see the empty fields are still not returned in the response.

I have used `reflect` package and ensured that `omitempty` tag is not set.

I dont have an option to use some thing like as shown below as that is applicable for all fields.

```
gwmux := runtime.NewServeMux(runtime.WithMarshalerOption(runtime.MIMEWildcard, &runtime.JSONPb{OrigName: true, EmitDefaults: true}))
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `json` tags have no bearing on how grpc-gateway ultimately ends up marshalling json in the response (the jsonpb package is used). You mention you don't want to have empty values rendered for all fields - are you talking about fields within a particular message, or are you thinking you'd want this behaviour to only apply to certain messages, but for all fields within those specified messages?

Answer (score 0):

This demo runtime version is v1, but your version is v2.

`gwmux := runtime.NewServeMux(runtime.WithMarshalerOption(runtime.MIMEWildcard, &runtime.JSONPb{OrigName: true, EmitDefaults: true}))`

(*) google.golang.org/protobuf replaces the now deprecated github.com/golang/protobuf and its jsonpb package.

runtime v2

```
import (
  "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/runtime"
  "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
)

gwMux := runtime.NewServeMux(
  runtime.WithMarshalerOption(runtime.MIMEWildcard, &runtime.JSONPb{
    MarshalOptions: protojson.MarshalOptions{
      EmitUnpopulated: true,
    },
  }),
)
```