# gRPC not returning boolean if value is false

Tags: go, grpc

```golang
func (m *TodoServer) GetTodos(ctx context.Context, empty *emptypb.Empty) (*desc.GetTodosResponse, error) {
    todos, err := m.todoService.GetTodos()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    todosResp := make([]*desc.GetTodosResponse_Todo, 0, len(todos))
    for _, todo := range todos {
        todosResp = append(todosResp, &desc.GetTodosResponse_Todo{
            Id:          todo.ID,
            Title:       todo.Title,
            IsCompleted: todo.IsCompleted,
        })
    }

    return &desc.GetTodosResponse{Todos: todosResp}, nil
}
```

```protobuf
service TodoService {
    rpc GetTodos(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (GetTodosResponse) {}
}

message GetTodosResponse {
    repeated Todo todos = 1;
    message Todo {
        int64 id = 1;
        string title = 2;
        bool is_completed = 3;
    }
}
```

I have one record in the db
| id | title | is_completed |
|-|-|-|
| 1 | aaa | false |

the function above returns `{"todos": [{"id": "1", "title": "aaa"}]}` but once I change the `is_completed` to `true` the result is correct `{"todos": [{"id": "1", "title": "aaa", "isCompleted": true}]}`

Comment: How do you print this result?

Comment: @tkausl getting this from my rest core service but it doesn't actually matter cause I'm losing this value after the for loop in the code above.

`log.Println("GetTodos: ", todosResp)` returns `GetTodos:  [id:1 title:"aaa"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design and for efficiency.

The "zero" value for a `bool` is `false` - so when initializing your `protobuf` struct with a `false` value, the field does not need to be explicitly stated when using the standard libary's `encoding/json` unmarshaler. On the encoding end, if the field's JSON tag includes an `omitempty` qualifier, the standard libary's `encoding/json` marshaler will remove any zero values - which is what you are seeing.
You will see the same behavior with the `Title` string field if it was `""` (i.e. the zero value of a string).

Looking at your generated code (`*.pb.go`) the struct's `bool` field definition will look something like this:

```
type Todo struct {
    // ...
    IsCompleted  bool  `protobuf:"varint,5,opt,name=is_complete,proto3" json:"is_complete,omitempty"`
}
```

So the `json:"...,omitempty"` instructs the `encoding/json` marshaler to omit any zero values during marshalling with tags like theses.

If you want to override this behavior:

- one could remove the `omitempty` directive from your generated code (not recommended - as edits would need to be managed over the lifecycle of development). But if you must, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37335452/1218512);
- if using `grpc-gateway`, override this at runtime e.g.

```
gwmux := runtime.NewServeMux(runtime.WithMarshalerOption(runtime.MIMEWildcard, &runtime.JSONPb{OrigName: true, EmitDefaults: true}))
```

- or if exporting the JSON yourself, instead of using the standard library (`encoding/json`) use the `JSON` marshaler from this package `"google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"`:

```
protojson.Marshaler{EmitDefaults: true}.Marshal(w, resp)
```

as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50044963/1218512).