# golang protobuff cant send empty map in reponse

Tags: go, grpc

I have a protobuff response defined as below

```
message Unit {
  string name = 1; 
  map<string, int32> category = 2;
}
```

in my golang-grpc service, i have this response to send back to client,

Issue -  when the map is empty, key is missing from the response.

```
{
  "units": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "category": {
        "3": 1,
        "6": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "abc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Required - even if the map is empty, key should be returned.

```
{
      "units": [
        {
          "name": "abc",
          "category": {
            "3": 1,
            "6": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "abc",
           "category": {
            
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716238/golang-protobuf-remove-omitempty-tag-from-generated-json-tags)